# How to draw lines between multiple Images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I need to visually show a line from one image to one or more images to represent a server connected to one or more servers. I'm assuming WPF is the best tool for this and am using this project to learn and evaluate WPF and determine if we should start migrating from WinForms.

I'm trying to keep the layout simple for purposes of re-sizing and managing the layout. So the image representing the source server is in the upper left and all connected servers are listed down the right side. I'm new to WPF and Expression Blend and have been struggling with how to draw the connectors. Right now I have the images in a grid. After some frustrating attempts to draw lines using tiled images I started to use a line with a GradientBrush which looks like a 2D pipe. This seemed like a decent approach. But I'm hoping there is an adequate method to draw a path similar to my mock up.

Thoughts...

- Put the lines in the grid and span multiple rows and columns
- Put the line on a canvas which spans all rows and columns
- I assume the line paths will need to be determined in the code behind, But I've been impressed with everything XAML is capable of.

I'm just a WPF noob and a little overwhelmed by everything that WPF can do. This seems like something that's been done many times before but I cannot find any related WPF examples and would prefer to minimize my frustrating attempts :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would  use `Canvas` instead of `Grid` because you can use [absolute positioning with Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514508%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Take a look at this 4 part series on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3) to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Seperator in between the images. Put seperator in a stackpanel so you can control its orientation to horizontal or vertical and you can also change its color and thickness. If you place seperator in a canvas you can also control its placement.